# Creating an install shield for Swing project with ressources

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, installshield

I have created a simple java application and it uses some external resources (folders). How can I create an install shield that creates a folder installation (like `C:\Program Files\MyApp`) and copy the external resources to this destination? I'm using Eclipse.

Comment: Do you mean copy the `external` not `past` resources to the folder?

Comment: @DavidKroukamp: both, sorry for my ambiguous Qt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why not rather create a fully self-contained Jar file with embedded resources.

Put your resources in the source/package folder and use:

[`getResource()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResource%28java.lang.String%29) or  [`getResourceAsStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#getResourceAsStream%28java.lang.String%29) to  retrieve an `URL` or `InputStream` of the *resource*:

- Extract a file from a different package in the Jar:

  ```
  package org.main //our package name
  ...
  Image img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/org/main/test.jpg"));
  ```
- Or if it is in the same package as the current class:

  ```
  Image img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("test.jpg"));
  ```

If you are looking for a Java install shield/wizard have a look at these open source applications:

- [Install4j](http://freecode.com/projects/install4j)
- [launch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/)
- [JSmooth](http://jsmooth.sourceforge.net/)
- [Packlet installer tool](http://packlet.sourceforge.net/)
- [and many many more](http://www.java2s.com/Product/Java/Development/Installer.htm) (not all free though)

Comment: What about creating an install shield, is there an open source software that can do that for java project?

Comment: There is a free open source project: [NSIS](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Main_Page) which was created by Winamp's developers. There seems to be a follow-up project: [UNSIS](http://code.google.com/p/unsis/). There is also a possibility to compile the source code on Linux and create "Real" Windows installers on Linux (see [this post](http://mohanjith.net/blog/2007/08/makensis-on-linux.html)).